# Azure DevOps - set work item auto-id numbering to begin from custom offset, e.g. 5000?

Tags: azure-devops

If switching from another backlog system to Azure DevOps, is it possible (in some admin settings) to set the start number/offset for auto-numbering of ids?

Say for instance, that we have item id's in our old backlog up to 4000 and want to continue this numbering.

Comment: All work items share the same sequence also.  So even if you were to start on 4000, you will end up with gaps in your numbering anyway if you are only looking at something at a specific level.  Azure DevOps supports Epics, Features, Tasks, etc.

Answer (score 4):

> *Work item ID*
>
> The unique identifier that is assigned to a work item. Work item IDs
>   are **unique** across all projects and within a project collection.

After a work item is created, you can modify all fields except for the ID. When you add and save a work item, **the ID is assigned by the system and cannot be changed**.

Sorry this is not able to do this. You could not use work item auto-id numbering to begin from custom offset, it's controlled by system.

You could create another customized field to set your customized IDs or follow *jessehouwing*'s suggestion above.

Answer (score 2):

No not really. You could use the API to create (and destroy) 4000 work items... That would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

To increment ID assigned by the system by creating and deleting items like describe in jessehouwing's suggestion, it's possible to use az cli (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest for more details).

To create an issue:

```
az boards work-item create --title dummy$i --type issue --organization [urlOfOrganisation] --project [projectName]
```

To delete it:

```
az boards work-item delete --id [identifier] --organization [urlOfOrganisation] --project [projectName]
```

For instance, to create XXX issues and delete them in bash:

```
i=1;  
while (( i < XXX )) ; do  
  az boards work-item create --title dummy$i --type issue --organization [urlOfOrganisation] --project [projectName]  --yes
  az boards work-item delete --id $i --organization [urlOfOrganisation] --project [projectName]  --yes
  (( i = i+1 ))
done
```